# Comparing while vs do-while loops

Tags: c, while-loop, do-while

I'm used to doing `while` loops -- and not even considering whether it would be in better interest to use a `while` or `do-while` loop -- out of familiarity. Here are two examples of a `do` vs `while` loop:

```
// do-while vs. while --
char *string = "String!";
int pos_d=0, pos_w=0;

// while
while (string[pos_w] != 0) {
    printf("At Pos %d The letter is: %c\n", pos_w, string[pos_w]);
    pos_w ++;
}

// do-while
do {
    printf("At Pos %d The letter is: %c\n", pos_d, string[pos_d]);
} while (string[pos_d++] != 0);
```

Obviously in the above case, the latter loop allows us to see the last character in the string (`\0`) whereas the while loop quits upon encountering that. What are some examples where a `do` loop would be used over a `while` loop? For example, couldn't a `do` loop be gotten rid of by just adding the same compound statement after the loop if it's needed. What might be some cases where a `do` loop is better (and should be encouraged) over a while loop?

Comment: The second do-while example isn't technically correct - it reads one past the end of the string. You should use a pre-increment instead: `} while (string[++pos_d] != 0);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C language was designed to allow even very simple compilers to produce reasonably efficient machine code.  While it would be possible to express `while(condition) {block};` as `if (condition) do {block} while(condition);` or to express `do {block} while(condition);` as `if (1) {block} do {block} while (condition);`, simple compilers would often generate somewhat different code for these alternative ways of writing the same thing, different ways of writing the code would yield better results in different cases.

For example, a common way for compilers to process `while(condition) {block};` is to treat it as equivalent to either:

```
loop:
  if (!condition) goto exit;
  {block};
  goto loop;
exit:
```

or as

```
  goto end;
loop:
  {block};
end:
  if (condition) goto loop;
```

If one were to rewrite the code as `if (condition) do {block} while(condition);` the result would be equivalent to:

```
  if (!condition) goto exit;
loop:
  {block};
  if (condition) goto loop
exit:
```

The code executed by all of these is identical except for conditional branches that are taken (T), conditional branches that are not taken (N), and unconditional jumps (U).  The costs of branches and jumps will vary between platforms, but one can determine how many of each kind of branch or jump will be required for each way of writing the code.  In particular, for the three ways of writing the code, the counts would be:

```
                  --First--  --Second-- --Third--
                  T  N  U    T  N  U    T  N  U
Zero iterations:  1  0  0    0  1  1    1  0  0 
One iteration:    1  1  1    1  1  1    0  2  0
Addl. iteration:  0  1  1    1  0  0    1  0  0
```

Note that the third approach requires the fewest branches and jumps for any number of iterations, but at the expense of duplicating the code required to test the condition.  On systems where the combined cost of an unconditional branch and a conditional branch not taken would exceed the cost of a conditional branch taken, the first approach will be cheaper in cases where a loop executes zero times, the costs will be the same if a loop executes exactly once, and the second will be cheaper if the loop executes two or more times.

If it's known that a loop is always going to execute at least once, the duplicated condition test and a non-taken branch can be eliminated from the third approach, making it a very clear winner.  It's also easier for compilers to generate code for than the second approach.  Having a `do {} while()` construct in the language makes it easier for simple compilers to easily generate efficient code in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you write some game. If someone opened the program then supposedly he wanted to play at least once, right?

```
int replay;
do
{
   // Game logic goes here

   //Game finishes

   printf("Wanna play again? Press 1 to replay. Press other number to quit. Your option: ");
   scanf("%d", &replay);
} while(replay == 1);
```

Of course you could do:

```
int replay = 1;
while(replay == 1)
{
   //Game logic goes here

   //Game finishes

   printf("Wanna play again? Press 1 to replay. Press other number to quit. Your option: ");
   scanf("%d", &replay);
}
```

But using `do while` for an occasion like this one could be more readable, don't you agree?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a do-while loop if you want to execute the loop body at least once and check the loop condition afterwards.
It provides better readability and maintainability for your co workers than e.g. using some counter variable.

You can use a do-while loop at least every time when you can guarantee that there is at least one iteration.

A concrete example which comes to my mind are parsers. There, I often see lots of do-while loops.